# Inner product space and positive define matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ Hermitian, $A^{*}=A$, and it is given that $X^{T}A\bar{X}>0$  for every $X\in\mathbb{C}^n$. Then $(u,v):=u^{T}A\bar{v}$ defines an inner product space over $\mathbb{C}^n$

Now, I managed to prove all properties, except $(u,v)=\overline{(v,u)}$.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: $(u^TA\overline{v})^T = \overline{v}^TA^Tu$, does that take you further?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes!

Answer (score 1):

Applying Daniel Fischer start:

$(u,v)=u^{T}A\bar{v}=(u^{T}A\bar{v})^T=(\bar{v}^TA^Tu)=\overline{\overline{\bar{v}^TA^Tu}}=\overline{v^TA^{*}\bar{u}}=\overline{v^TA\bar{u}}=\overline{(v,u)}$